# Styling a javascript popup window on shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'd really appreciate some help with this - I'm not really a developer/programmer, just sort of ended up doing this at work!

I need a popup to display a discount coupon to only the visitors from Canada. Step one was figuring out a script to identify these visitors, which I did. My knowledge of JS is very limited though so I used open.window for the popup which doesn't really allow me to style the window. I want the popup to look like a fancybox popup but can't add that to the shopify theme (tried and didn't work).

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Here's the code:

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax( {
url: 'https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(location) {

if (location.address.country === 'Canada') {

  window.open("","","width=300, height=100");
 }
}
} ); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you to use sweet alert the are really easy to use and kind of fabulous in front end made a look :

1 ) download the sweet Alert zip and extract it .

2 ) check the dist folder and move the .min.js and the css file to your project .

3 ) use them as defineed in the documentation [here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) .

4) for you example it will be kind of

```
    <script>

jQuery.ajax( {
url: 'https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(location) {
if (location.address.country === 'Canada') {
  swal("confrats you choosed Canada");
 }
}
} ); 

</script>
```

hope it helped a little bit 
NB : dont forget to load the css file first and the the JS file

Comment: Hey, thanks a mill but I managed to figure it out without downloading sweet alert. I posted how I did it - not sure how sound it is from a programmer's point of view but it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax( {
url: 'https://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(location) {

if (location.address.country === 'Canada') {

if(localStorage.getItem('myModal') != 'shown'){     
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
localStorage.setItem('myModal','shown')
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

window.onload = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}

}
}
} );

</script>

HTML:

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">&nbsp;&#10006;&nbsp;</a>
<img src="img.jpg" style="padding-top:20px;">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: hidden; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
text-align: center;
width: 440px; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
height: 440px;
position:relative;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: arial black;
background-color: grey;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
right: -18px;
top: -18px;
border: 2px solid white;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```